# How to make React Redux async action return a promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, es6-promise, redux-thunk

I have a redux action function that returns a promise. Inside that function body, there is another async function that returns a callback when it finished the call. Then I call this function in another place chaining it with `.then()` but when debugging it in the browser with breakpoints, the promise function exists after the first two lines of code

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
```

is it because of the second return statement? This is the `react/redux` code so I must have a second return statement for my async Thunk redux action. How can I achieve this? So that I could call it in another redux action and chain it with `handleProfileImageUploadToS3().then(() => {...})` ?

Full function body:

```
export const handleProfileImageUploadToS3 = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
      const settingsState = getState().BusinessSettings
      const userState = getState().User
      const imageUpload = true

      if (!settingsState.get('logoImage') || settingsState.get('logoImage') === null) {
        reject('no image selected')
        return
      }
      Utilities.uploadFileToS3(
        imageUpload,
        settingsState.get('logoImage'),
        'apiurl',
        `profiles/${userState.get('id')}`,
        (error, url) => {
          if (error) {
            dispatch(uploadProfileSettingsImageError(error))
            return
          }
          dispatch(updateProfileImageUrlAfterUpload(url))
          resolve(url)
        }
      )
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing your whole codebase but there are some red flags in this function that I'm concerned about.

- The `BusinessSettings` and `User` properties of your state seem to be [non-serializable](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions) objects with a `get()` method.
- If the S3 upload gives an error then you `dispatch` and `return` but you never `resolve` or `reject` the `Promise`.
- The rejection from `reject('no image selected')` is unlikely to be caught anywhere.
- It seems like an un-uploaded image should be something that is stored in your UI state and passed as an argument rather than stored in Redux.  You would want to store the URL after it's uploaded.  This also removes the need for that rejection.

---

You are addressing two separate concerns in this function and I would recommend that you separate the two.

First is that you have a function `Utilities.uploadFileToS3` which uses a success/failure callback and you want to convert it to an async function (one that returns a `Promise`).

I would make a helper that takes just the arguments which vary and ignores those that are constant (like `'apiurl'`).

```
const asyncUploadFileToS3 = (image, userId) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Utilities.uploadFileToS3(
      true,
      image,
      "apiurl",
      `profiles/${userId}`,
      (error, url) => (url ? resolve(url) : reject(error))
    );
  });
};
```

---

Now that you have that part settled, you can approach writing the thunk in a more typical way.  You can return a `Promise` by `.then()` chaining or by making the function `async` and using a `try`/`catch` block.  By we don't need to wrap the whole thing in a `new Promise` because we've dealt with that on the `asyncUploadFileToS3` function.

You *can* return a result from the thunk and chain it, but I'm not sure what actually makes the most sense here.

```
export const handleProfileImageUploadToS3 = (image) => 
  async ( dispatch, getState ) => {
    const userId = getState().user.id;
    try {
      const url = await asyncUploadFileToS3(image, userId);
      dispatch(updateProfileImageUrlAfterUpload(url));
      return "this is the result";
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(uploadProfileSettingsImageError(error));
      return "there was an error";
    }
  };
```

```
export default function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const avatar = useSelector((state) => state.user.imageUrl);

  const onClick = () => {
    const image = new Blob();
    dispatch(handleProfileImageUploadToS3(image)).then(
      // logs "this is the result" or "there was an error"
      (returned) => console.log("finished", returned)
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Upload</button>
      {avatar ? <div>Avatar URL: {avatar}</div> : <div>No Avatar</div>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Code Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-thunk-image-promise-yenr6?file=/src/components/App.tsx)

Comment: Thanks for a comprehensive answer. There is a lot to absorb. 
"It seems like an un-uploaded image should be something that is stored in your UI state and passed as an argument rather than stored in Redux." I actually do that. I store the image blob in a local state and only save it to redux store on button click to save. I save the File object in redux store that I use to upload to S3, get the url back, update the store from File object to a generated URL from S3 and then call another action to save that URL to database.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I found out that you must return another function from initial Promise function before returning `new Promise` to have access to Redux `dispatch` and `getState` methods, instead of returning it as anonymous function right inside `new Promise()` code block which then just exits the function execution. Here is the full code:

```
export const handleProfileImageUploadToS3 = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const settingsState = getState().BusinessSettings
    const userState = getState().User
    const imageUpload = true

    if (!settingsState.get('logoImage') || settingsState.get('logoImage') === null) {
      reject('no image selected')
      return
    }
    Utilities.uploadFileToS3(
      imageUpload,
      settingsState.get('logoImage'),
      'apiurl',
      `profiles/${userState.get('id')}`,
      (error, url) => {
        if (error) {
          dispatch(uploadProfileSettingsImageError(error))
          return
        }
        dispatch(updateProfileImageUrlAfterUpload(url))
        resolve(url)
      }
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: Do you need a `resolve` or `reject` inside of the `if(error)`?  Seems like it might hang there forever.  If it were me personally I would address the two issues separately.  Those issues being 1) you need to create a `Promise` wrapper around the  `Utilities.uploadFileToS3` function since it's not `async` and 2) you need to create a thunk dispatch that uses that function.  When you `reject` here with "no image selected", is that caught anywhere?

Comment: `settingsState` is a piece of your Redux state, but you are calling `settingsState.get('logoImage')` which is very strange to me because your Redux state should be raw serializable data.  It should not have a `get()` method.  (same for `userState.get('id')`).

Comment: @LindaPaiste It doesn't hang in `Utilities.uploadFileToS3() `callback, by using breakpoints I found that the function was exeting at the second line of code which is return `(dispatch, getState) => {}` I'm still not sure why though. And `Utilities.uploadFileToS3()` is an async function on its own but it uses callback instead of promises. Should I use reject inside its callback as well if it fails? 
"2) you need to create a thunk dispatch that uses that function" - what is the difference between using it as I do right now versus dispatching it as an action of its own? Works well as it is now.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I'm not sure regarding the redux store calling, we do it like this all over the project and I was introduced to this project very recently, so I'm not sure what are the good practices of redux. This is how that reducer looks: 
`const getInitialState = () => {
  return Map({
    logoImage: '',
    brandName: '',
    website: '',
    countryCode: '',
    currency: '',
    vat: '',
  })
}`

Comment: It is not a good idea to use a `Map`.  Just store that  object without the `Map` around it.  [With Redux, our application state is always kept in plain JavaScript objects and arrays. That means you may not put other things into the Redux state - no class instances, built-in JS types like Map / Set Promise / Date, functions, or anything else that is not plain JS data.](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#designing-the-state-structure)

Comment: Per your other comment about separating the two issues, that's more of a code style / design thing.  It's not inherently a problem but I think the way I've written it in my answer is better.